# VMware works slow after some time

Tags: vmware

I own a lets say a decent laptop  with 6gb ram and i5 4CPUs ~2.5 Ghz and I create a virtual machine with half of my resources with default options, I don't change anything and after some time let's say 1h OR if I don't to nothing on virtual machine the cpu start to idle and if I came back to the virtual machine it works VERY slow, looks like the VM freeze or something. There is any options to improve performance on VMware? Why it freeze? Also sometimes the vmware crash. Any tips?

**EDIT**
I installed a new version of vmware I will comeback to an answer after a few hours too see how it goes...

**SOLVED** Works great with the last version of VMware... the version which cause me probles was from 2013.

Comment: What's running in the VM? If you look at the system resource use graphs (RAM, processor, etc), how do they look? Possibly a memory/process leak.. or perhaps your machine is overheating, and then throttling performance?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64x I running, the cpu stay at 10%-15%.. looks like he don't want to work

Comment: RAM use within the VM? Processes running? Temperature?

Comment: Is this a suddenly occurring problem (i.e. you've had no problems with VM until today)?

Comment: I just installed it and also I just installed my windows on local machine everything is clean.

Answer (score 0):

When you have i5 and 6GB of ram. VMware should run perfectly fine. Make sure that there are no other applications running in your base operating system. 
The probable reasons can be insufficient RAM or CPU over heat.You dont have to allot half of your resources until and unless you are going to use them in your virtual machine. 
If possible reinstall your VMware with optimum resources. Need not to be half of your system.

Comment: I tried first with less resources and I say ok i have to add more but the problem persist.